# How to use light box on posted images that are extracted from database

Tags: php, html, css, lightbox2

I am trying to create a forums where my php file extracts the replies to the thread from my database and displays them in a foreach loop.

for example:

```
<?php 

        if(sizeof($arr_posts) > 0){
                foreach ($arr_posts as $posts){
                        echo $posts;
                }
        }
?>
```

So `$arr_posts` holds the posts to this thread. So element of the array holds a html block that displays the post on the page.

However, the issue I have spent days on (not kiddig). When a user has submitted a reply with an image. I.e.

```
'Look at this dog <img src="dog.png">'
```

I want a lightbox theme to expand the image to make it bigger to zoom in. However, I have struggled to somehow get the lightbox by lokesh around the image tag in order for this to work. I needed to get this:

```
'Look at this dog <a href="/images/dog.png><img src="images/dog.png"></a>'
```

is there some other way I can do this? Any suggestions are welcoming. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$html, $result);
```

and replace anythings you want with `$result` in loops

Comment: so this gets the img tag, but how can i can a reinsert the anchored image back where it was in the original message ?

Comment: @kongar you should be extract image url and replace orginal image tag with <a href="">img tag</a> in original string